# How to get your iOS app to QA to test

Tags: iphone

I am familiar with 3rd parties like TestFlight but is there a way through Xcode to distribute your application to your QA department for testing? For example is there an easy way to do a .ipa file so that QA can use iTunes on windows to load the application onto their test device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes ,you can use Apple's Wireless distribution
follow this [tutorial](http://aaronparecki.com/How_to_Distribute_your_iOS_Apps_Over_the_Air).

Answer (score 0):

You want to do AdHoc distribution. This is exactly what TestFlight does, they just make it easier.